# DDev Ports are not available

Tags: docker, docker-desktop, ddev

I have a DDev project in WSL2. Whenever I try to start it I get an error:

```
Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 127.0.0.1:443 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:443: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.'
```

Sometimes it's also port 80. But most importantly before starting the project none of those ports is occupied. Neither inside WSL nor on the Windows Host. I am also able to start another docker container exposing on those ports. I am even to manually start the router with

```
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=ddev-project docker-compose -f /home/crs/.ddev/.router-compose-full.yaml -p ddev-router up -d
```

but I still can't access the project even though the router seems to be running.

`ddev debug test` also fails.

I tried updating and reinstalling both Docker Desktop and ddev.

I also tried changing the `router_http_port` and `router_https_port` to something else. Then it does seem to start the project but I still can't access anything through the ddev router.

The web containers seem to work fine, when not going through the router I can access the project.

Comment: Fixed for now by switching from docker CE inside WSL instead of Docker Desktop. But that still doesn't explain the root of the problem. Maybe an issue with Docker Desktop?

Answer (score 0):

Debugging for this is explained in the [docs](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/usage/troubleshooting/#web-server-ports-already-occupied), but it's slightly trickier on WSL2, because the process that's giving trouble may be either on the Windows side or the WSL2 side.

As explained there, you can either find the competing process or change to use different ports in DDEV.

On WSL2, port 80 is often apache2, which some distros have by default, so you can stop it or uninstall it without any harm.  Port 443 is something occupied by random poorly behaved processes on Windows, including sometimes virus checkers.

If you use the techniques there to check for competing ports you'll almost certainly solve this.

Another technique is to use `curl localhost`, `curl -I localhost` or `curl https://localhost` and `curl -I https://localhost` to see if the HTTP response gives you a clue what process is problematic.

Also note that sometimes Docker Desktop is poorly behaved if you're using it, and you may have to restart it.

But if changing the ports to, say, 8080 and 8443 didn't solve it for you then you have a connectivity problem, likely a firewall. That's a completely different problem and you'll want to walk through the troubleshooting instructions in [docs](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/usage/troubleshooting/#general-troubleshooting-strategies) and start with temporarily turning off firewall and VPN.

For more interactive help, join us in the [DDEV Discord](https://discord.gg/hCZFfAMc5k).

Comment: I am very sure there are no ports listening before I start ddev, not on the Windows side and not on the WSL side. I checked that with `ss` on the WSL side and `netstat` on the Windows side. However for some reason 80 and 443 are listening after starting even if I change `router_http(s)_port` to something else. 
Also even with all firewalls disabled I can't access any other ports from the Windows side even if the Docker Desktop shows them to be exposed and they are listening inside the container (checked by attaching a shell to the ddev-router container)

Comment: If you're running WSL higher than 1.0.3.0 there are massive troubles with it in communicating with the windows side, see https://github.com/drud/ddev/issues/4573

Comment: OK that seems to be my problem too. Using WSL version 1.1.2.0

Comment: They just released WSL 1.1.3, which they say fixes this, https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/9508